# Copying Kubernetes Secret Between Namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I attempted to replicate the `dd-es-remote-ca` secret from the `default` namespace into the `kube-system` namespace. Despite encountering no errors during the process, the secret did not successfully copy over.

```
% kubectl --namespace default get secret dd-es-remote-ca -o yaml | sed 's/namespace: default/namespace: kube-system/'
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: 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
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-02-07T20:57:58Z"
  labels:
    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name: dd
  name: dd-es-remote-ca
  namespace: kube-system
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: Elasticsearch
    name: dd
    uid: 21e623d1-8711-4273-8d55-82d7f85ea5eb
  resourceVersion: "84366"
  uid: ec59fa6f-910c-4934-bdca-9f5105a67512
type: Opaque
%
% kubectl get secret dd-es-remote-ca --namespace default -o yaml | sed 's/namespace: default/namespace: kube\-system/g' | kubectl apply -f -
secret/dd-es-remote-ca created
% kubectl --namespace kube-system get secrets
No resources found in kube-system namespace.
%
```

what am I doing wrong? please advise)
thank you!

---

```
% kubectl --namespace default get secret dd-es-remote-ca -o yaml | yq 'del ( .metadata.creationTimestamp, .metadata.resourceVersion, .metadata.uid )' | sed 's/namespace: default/namespace: kube-system/' | kubectl apply -f -
secret/dd-es-remote-ca created
% kubectl --namespace kube-system get secrets
No resources found in kube-system namespace.
% kubectl --namespace default get secret dd-es-remote-ca -o yaml | yq 'del ( .metadata.creationTimestamp, .metadata.resourceVersion, .metadata.uid )' | sed 's/namespace: default/namespace: kube-system/'
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: 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
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name: dd
  name: dd-es-remote-ca
  namespace: kube-system
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: Elasticsearch
      name: dd
      uid: 21e623d1-8711-4273-8d55-82d7f85ea5eb
type: Opaque
%
```

Comment: Have you inspected the output of the `sed` expression to make sure it looks like you expect before passing it to `kubectl apply`?

Comment: yes, it is almost exactly the same) with an exception of namespace variable

Comment: That looks good to me. Is there anything specific about the secret itself? What type is this?

Comment: @user23204747 updated my Q and added all w/out last pipe and kubectl apply, so you can see _exactly_..

Comment: Strip `creationTimestamp`, `resourceVersion` and `uid`?

Comment: @AlexD updated my Q w/ stripped `creationTimestamp`,`resourceVersion`,`uid`, yet same result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you are facing is due to `metadata.ownerReferences` of your original object. As per:

```
kubectl explain secret.metadata.ownerReferences
```

> List of objects depended by this object. If ALL objects in the list have been deleted, this object will be garbage collected. ... An owning object must be in the same namespace as the dependent, or
> be cluster-scoped, so there is no namespace field.

As there is no owning object for the secret in the target namespace, it gets garbage collected.